# What is the reason for subtracting 16 ^ 6 in decimal representation of color codes?

Tags: java, php, colors, rgb, rgba

I found a strange specification for representing color with a single integer variable in a project.

In that specification, the formulator used the value which converted the rgb color into a decimal number and subtracted 16 ^ 6.
For example, in the case of yellow, it is (255, 255, 0) in rgb, so it is FFFF00 in hexadecimal, so converting it to decimal, it is 16776960. The problem is that after this, in the specification I found, the formulator used the value "-256" (16776960 minus 16 ^ 6) as an integer value to represent color.

Are these specifications common?
Why don't you use 16776960 as it is?
(Not because it will be short. For example, in the case of black, it is 0 in decimal, but -16777216 (0-16 ^ 6) is used.)

Note:
Since I did not look at the source code, it was reproduced only by chance according to the algorithm described here, and it is not necessarily the code written in the same way of thinking as described here. The application side is Java, the back end is a project written in PHP, the influence of those libraries may be related.

Comment: What specification? Perhaps there's a color table? It's impossible to say without seeing the formula (or at least the specification).

Comment: Sorry, "specification" was too strong expression. Actually, I just want to say the application's way of saving color code as a single integer variable.  I thought simple converting is enough, and that's why I ask this question.

Comment: If you calculate, `16^6` is `1000000` so `1 00 00 00`. To me it seems a trick for signed to unsigned (or contrary). Note if you have also Alpha, the number could be negative, but without alpha, probably it is still 32-bit, so you have somewhere a byte. Is it just possible that the code was copied from C or asm, without understanding. In any case, without original code, it is difficult to tell you "why"